# CastleWindsor:FromAssemblyInDirectory - how to add from multiple directories?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

Consider the following registration code i'm using:

```
container.Install(FromAssembly.InDirectory(new AssemblyFilter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)),
            FromAssembly.InDirectory(new AssemblyFilter(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Jobs"))));
```

This is the simplest line in a bunch of registrations i do, where i'm picking DLLs from both the base directory as well as a "Jobs" subdirectory. What's the syntax (if any?) for merging two assemblyfilters? Because i obviously don't want to duplicate registration code.... and it gets uglier with bigger registrations.

I thought of trying to write a small class myself to do it, but alas all the functions take AssemblyFilter as argument instead of IAssemblyProvider? So no go there.....

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about any support of this in Windsor, but to prevent duplicity of registration I always extract the registration into helper function with directory parameter. eg.

```
static BasedOnDescriptor Connectors(string directory)
{
    return Classes.
        FromAssemblyInDirectory(new AssemblyFilter(directory)).
        BasedOn<IConnector>().
        LifestyleTransient().
        ConfigureDiagnostics();
}
```

And then register it like:

```
container.Register(
    Connectors("Connectors"),
    Connectors("."));
```